# color an image using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to color the various parts of an image like this demo `http://www.nickjr.com/kids-games/color-with-dora.html`. This demo uses flash. Is there any possibility do this in javascript or jquery?

Please give any reference.

Comment: jQuery is a library of third party JavaScript functions, not an alternative to JavaScript.

Comment: Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript. And if you decide to use jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: We couldn't find any demo like our example.

Comment: Perhaps look into [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG) or maybe more specifically Raphael

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how to re-create a entire small application, so to keep this answer to a manageable length, I'm simplifying it to two basic needs: (1) being able to click on a color palette to choose a color, (2) filling parts of a picture with that color.  I'm making a lot of assumptions about what you want since the question is fairly general.

Example:  [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7MQH/)

(Disclaimer: I have no idea how cross-browser compatible the demo is -- it works on Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m, that's all I know).

The two basic parts are this:

1. Use [SVG elements](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp) to represents your picture.  The parts of the picture can be filled by changing the 'fill' property on the SVG elements.  (You may be able to export the SVG directly from drawing application such as Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator.)
2. Use jQuery to associate a mouse [click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) with color selection and applying that color when changing the fill.

The code in the demo is fairly basic jQuery and SVG.  Hopefully it's enough to get you going toward what you more specifically need.